# Logind and gdbus: Not getting notifications

Tags: c++, glib, systemd, dbus

I use DBus to communicate with logind to get informations about active sessions, etc. I have created the code using `gdbus-codegen`. I can get informations by using the `call` and `get` methods, but I do not receive notifications (I have a `g_main_loop` running!).

I create the session object like this:

```
GError *error;
session_ = ::login1_session_proxy_new_for_bus_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM,
                                                   G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_NONE,
                                                   "org.freedesktop.login1",
                                                   object_path,
                                                   NULL,
                                                   &error);
```

with `object_path` beeing the path described above and verified using a debugger.

I do not know is this has something to do with the problem not getting notifications.

I register the callback like this:

```
::g_signal_connect_data(proxy, "notify::active", G_CALLBACK(&cb_thunk), this, 0, (GConnectFlags)0);
```

(I use `g_signal_connect_data` to set the `userdata` to my current class, as I am writing this in C++ and using callback thunks).

The callback function has this signature:

```
static void cb_thunk(proxy_t *proxy, first_data_t param1, second_data_t param2, gpointer userdata);
```

with `proxy_t` beeing defined as `Login1Session` (generated from `gdbus-codegen`).

Am I making a mistake here? I do not understand why I am not getting any notifications on this.

Callbacks via DBus are working, but not with properties, only with real callback functions in dbus.

Comment: Edited: The assertion part is gone, there was something wrong in my XML Files for `gdbus-codegen`

Comment: Okay, I don't have domain knowledge here, so I might be wrong and the provided information may actually be enough to help, but this looks like it's missing a [MCVE].

Comment: The problem is that no signal gets emitted. providing an example is difficult because it requires stuff around the code. a system with systemd and logind on a multiuser environment with fast user switching...

Comment: If the problem is only reproducible with "stuff around the code" that we don't know about, I don't see how anyone could help. Feels like a guessing game to me. But as I said, I have no domain knowledge, so maybe someone with indepth knowledge of these systems can actually tell your problem from those 3 lines of code. Best of luck!

Comment: Is it possible that "active" property is never toggled?

Comment: at least the value changes. i watch the value on the command line via gdbus and at least is switches from true to false when switching a VT

Comment: If you watch the emissions from logind using `sudo gdbus monitor --system --dest org.freedesktop.login1`, is a `PropertiesChanged` signal actually emitted for the `active` property on the object path you specified? If you watch all D-Bus traffic from when you start your program (using `sudo dbus-monitor --system`), do you see an `AddMatch` call from your program with an appropriate match string for receiving the signal emissions from logind?

Comment: The signals are emitted. dbus monitor will show them

Answer (score -1):

gdbus is a higher level language on top of the dbus protocol. It is hard to say why you don't get signals on the higher level but I think the best way forward is to make sure lower layer works. That means the dbus signals are emitted in the dbus protocol level. For this, I would snoop the dbus message bus (system bus). As a privileged process (root) execute `busctl monitor` and look at the traffic.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19990613)

Comment: I have to agree with @Flovdis, this should not be an answer. Yes, the lower level works, the signals are emitted, I watched this with dbus monitor over an ssh connection while switching sessions.